# Transparent Android activity trouble

Tags: android, android-layout

I have an application where the theme can be changed between three different ones. I have two activities that are supposed to have a transparent background and look like a dialog above the previous activity.

I've searched alot for transparent activities here on stack and most of them have the same awnsers. A custom theme with a few properties to enable a transparent background for the activity in question.

The issue for me is that i need to set this custom transparent theme on the parent activity as well to achieve any transparency at all. If i only set a transparent theme on the activity i want to be transparent, it will be a solid background. I've tried everything i could think of but it all boils down to this and im not sure what im doing wrong.

This is my two different parent themes (slimmed down to the neccesary parts):

```
<style name="StyledActionbar" parent="Theme.Sherlock.Light.ForceOverflow">
    <item name="android:textViewStyle">@style/Iksu.TextView</item>

    <item name="windowContentOverlay">@null</item>
    <item name="android:windowContentOverlay">@null</item>
</style>

<style name="Transparent" parent="Theme.Sherlock.Light.ForceOverflow">
    <item name="android:textViewStyle">@style/TextView</item>

    <item name="windowContentOverlay">@null</item>
    <item name="android:windowContentOverlay">@null</item>

    <item name="android:windowIsTranslucent">true</item>
</style>
```

StyledActionBar is the parent for my three different main themes that is used for all activities that are not supposed to have a transparent background (which is all but two).

Transparent is the parent for three themes that can be used on an activity where the background needs to be transparent.

So the parent activity has a theme based on the StyledActionBar theme. The activity i need to have transparent is based on the Transparent theme.

The background is solid in this state.

If i move:

```
<item name="android:windowIsTranslucent">true</item>
```

to StyledActionBar, almost everything works as a charm except a nasty bug in Android 4.4.2 causing the main activity to "fall behind" the OS view when using NavUtils for up-navigation to the main activity.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in your manigest file

```
   <activity           
        android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Translucent.NoTitleBar">
   </activity>
```

and in your xml set

```
 android:background="@android/transperent"
```

also you can use

```
android:alpha="0.50"
```

Answer (score 0):

try this one more time :

```
<style name="Theme.Transparent" parent="android:Theme">  
          <item name="android:windowIsTranslucent">true</item>  
          <item name="android:windowBackground">@android:color/transparent</item>  
          <item name="android:windowContentOverlay">@null</item>  
          <item name="android:windowNoTitle">true</item>  
          <item name="android:windowIsFloating">true</item>  
          <item name="android:backgroundDimEnabled">false</item>  
    </style>
```

and in the manifest file

```
<activity android:name=".AlertActivity"
                    android:theme="@style/Theme.Transparent"/>
```

Hope it will work for u.